# Javascript created Checkbox does not close off tag properly

Tags: javascript

If I create a checkbox like this, and add it to my table [TD] tag :

```
var chkBx = document.createElement('input');
chkBx.type = 'checkbox';

td.appendChild(chkBx);
```

it will create

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" value="Current Issue">
    </td>
</tr>
```

This input tag has not been closed off propertly. This is causing problems elsewhere in my code (for example the hover doesnt work).

Is there something i need to do in my Javascript to get this to close off properly?

Comment: How are you getting that HTML? The DOM elements which you are creating do not have "tags" that needed to be "closed".

Comment: What problems does this cause? What parses this HTML markup?

Comment: but shouldnt the input field be finished off with a backslash, to make it well formed? If i look at this in JSFiddle it complains

Comment: if I put a tr:hover styling on my table rows, it doesnt work. According to other sources this is because the TD tags need to be correctly finished

Comment: "but shouldnt the input field be finished off with a backslash, to make it well formed?" **No**, because the browser is creating an element, not a tag. Being well-formed applies to markup, not DOM elements. There must be something else affecting your hover. Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Can you manually fiddle the html to confirm this is in fact the problem rather than relying on other sources?

Comment: [No, they do not](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/syntax.html#void-elements). HTML is not XHTML. And btw, you're not creating HTML marking - you're just inserting elements into the DOM. jsfiddle never sees that `<input type="checkbox" value="Current Issue">` tag.

Comment: ok will do.. itll take a bit tho. Here is what i mean with JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Na7J2/1/    the tags after the input are red.

Comment: @OliverWatkins: That's just insufficient syntax highlighting, your HTML is still valid. And [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Na7J2/2/) would be completely fine.

Comment: Yes, those tags are red. This is because the syntax highlighter in jsFiddle expects well-formed XHTML for your **tags** (markup). **Elements** are created via JavaScript and are not subject to well-formedness. The browser is not going to create an invalid element.

Comment: here is the root problem. I am trying to highlight TR rows. I guess I was wrong, it has nothing to do with well formedness. http://jsfiddle.net/kUTDB/2/

Comment: actually going to post questions on that fiddle that i have now. Incase you have a solution to it, find my latest question

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the DOCTYPE you're using. XHTML requires closing tags, HTML doesn't. I think the browser automatically decides whether closing tags are required or not for dynamically created elements, depending on the DOCTYPE.

There also seems to be a problem in the parser on jsfiddle. It doesn't work without a closing tag, although the markup is validated correctly at the W3C validator.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selectors are not selecting anything.

```
.Table .Popup tr:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

should be:

```
.Popup tr:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

(See: http://jsfiddle.net/kUTDB/4/)

and

```
.Table .Popup .PopupRow:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

should be

```
table tr.PopupRow:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

or

```
table .PopupRow:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

(See: http://jsfiddle.net/kUTDB/5/)

Mind you, these will both select the same elements so the selector with more [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) (the second one) will be the one that is actually used.

Your first selector, `.Table .Popup tr:hover` will match `tr` elements that are currently being hovered over **and** that are descendants of any element with a class of `Popup` which are in turn descendants of any element of with a class of `Table`.

Your second selector, `.Table .Popup .PopupRow:hover` will match any elements with a class of `PopupRow` that are currently being hovered over **and** that are descendants of any element with a class of `Popup` which are in turn descendants of any element of with a class of `Table`.

The markup in your fiddle does not reflect that structure and so nothing is matched by the selectors (which is why your style is not reflected).