# Cannot make CSS hover work on TR in table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my table rows highlight when i hover my mouse over them

```
.Table .Popup tr:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Seems to work find on **TD** tags, but I seem to have trouble getting it to work for **TR** tags :

Fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/kUTDB/2/

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proper CSS should be this:

```
.Popup tr:hover td {
    background-color:red;
}

.Popup .PopupRow:hover td {
    background-color:red;
}
```

You can't (reliably) style a `<tr>`, so you need to apply the style to children `<td>`s on hover (hence `tr:hover td`.

Additionally, the `.Table` class doesn't refer to any elements in your fiddle, which may also be causing problems.

Comment: yes. The .Table class was a typo. But you nailed it with the core problem

Answer (score 3):

http://jsfiddle.net/kUTDB/12/

You can just do:

```
td:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this

```
.PopupContainer .Popup tr:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kUTDB/9/)

Answer (score 2):

Your CSS selector was incorrect:

Both

```
table tr:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

and

```
table .PopupRow:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

will work here.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kUTDB/7/

---

if you needed to be very specific, you could use this selector:

```
div.PopupContainer div.Popuptable table tbody tr.PopupRow:hover{
```

However, since longer selectors cost time, the more broad selectors are better. Really, you only need `.PopupRow:hover` here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the td

```
tr:hover td {
     background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473890/javascript-created-checkbox-does-not-close-off-tag-properly/):

Your CSS selectors are not selecting anything.

```
.Table .Popup tr:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

should be:

```
.Popup tr:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

(See: http://jsfiddle.net/kUTDB/4/)

and

```
.Table .Popup .PopupRow:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

should be

```
table tr.PopupRow:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

or

```
table .PopupRow:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

(See: http://jsfiddle.net/kUTDB/5/)

Mind you, these will both select the same elements so the selector with more [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) (the second one) will be the one that is actually used.

Your first selector, `.Table .Popup tr:hover` will match `tr` elements that are currently being hovered over **and** that are descendants of any element with a class of `Popup` which are in turn descendants of any element of with a class of `Table`.

Your second selector, `.Table .Popup .PopupRow:hover` will match any elements with a class of `PopupRow` that are currently being hovered over **and** that are descendants of any element with a class of `Popup` which are in turn descendants of any element of with a class of `Table`.

The markup in your fiddle does not reflect that structure and so nothing is matched by the selectors (which is why your style is not reflected).

Answer (score 1):

.Popup tr:hover {
    background-color:red;

}
This will totally work.